Structures inside custom section are inverted when compiling with aarch64-none-elf-gcc
When I compile using gcc for x86, the structures are placed in the section in the order I declare them. However, when I compile using aarch64-none-elf-gcc for an ARM target, the structures appear to be placed in the section in reverse order.
typedef struct test_t {
    char *test_name;
} test_t;

test_t test1 __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = { "Test 1" };
test_t test2 __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = { "Test 2" };
test_t test3 __attribute__((section("my_section"))) = { "Test 3" };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    extern __start_my_section;
    extern __stop_my_section;

    for (test_t *t = &__start_my_section; t != &__stop_my_section; t++) {
        printf("%s\n",t->test_name);
    }

    return 0;
}

when building with gcc on x86 , this prints
Test1
Test2
Test3

but, when building with aarch64-none-elf-gcc for an aarch64 target, i get
Test3
Test2
Test1

any body know why?

Compiler internals.

Is the order important to you?  If so, then you need to take appropriate action to ensure the wanted layout of the section. A custom linker script affords the greatest control, but there are some things you could do on the C side, too.

Source order of global-scope things is irrelevant to layout of an object file / executable.  Same as local variable layout in a stack frame, for example.  If you group them as members of one struct, or an array, that would enforce the layout.

How objects are stored in the section is up to compiler which places them in the object file.
If you want to be sure that objects will be placed in a specific order in your section, you need to modify your linker script
.my_section :
{
    KEEP(*(my_section*))
}

or
.my_section :
{
    KEEP(SORT_BY_NAME(*(my_section*)))  
}

test_t test1 __attribute__((section("my_section1"))) = { "Test 1" };
test_t test2 __attribute__((section("my_section2"))) = { "Test 2" };
test_t test3 __attribute__((section("my_section3"))) = { "Test 3" };

Then it should always be placed in the desired order  in .my_section

The order i'm talking about is the declaration order, not the content based order

@elhadidpıpɐɥןǝ I answered both. 1st. You have no control 2nd. You have control. If you want to have a control you need to take action otherwise - do you care?
